# Formatting data from a PDO Mysql query

Tags: php, html

I've got a mysql query using pdo, the issue is the data won't line up in a table.  Any suggestions?  I would like it to look like a standard html table or something.  I'm open to any suggestions.

```
foreach($results as $row) {
echo "<table width='900'>";
echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo htmlspecialchars($row['serial']) . "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo htmlspecialchars($row['model']) . "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo htmlspecialchars($row['deviceCondition']) . "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo htmlspecialchars($row['sealCondition']) . "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo htmlspecialchars($row['location']) . "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo htmlspecialchars($row['deployDate']) . "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo htmlspecialchars($row['weight']) . "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo htmlspecialchars($row['notes']) . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";

    //Arrays
    $serials [] = htmlspecialchars($row['serial']); //serial as an array
    $models [] = htmlspecialchars($row['model']); //model as an array
    $deviceConditions [] = htmlspecialchars($row['deviceCondition']);//deviceCondition as an array
    $locations [] = htmlspecialchars($row['location']); //location as an array
    $deployDates [] = htmlspecialchars($row['deployDate']); //deployDate as an array
    $weights [] = htmlspecialchars($row['weight']); //weight as an array
    $notess [] = htmlspecialchars($row['notes']); //notes as an array
}
```

Comment: place your `<table></table>` tags and `<tr></tr>` outside the loop. you're creating those for each row

Comment: Sometimes you wonder why you bother

Comment: Don't use `htmlspecialchars` when assigning to the arrays. That should only be used when displaying on a webpage.

Answer (score 1):

If you generate the HTML properly things will work better.

So think before you code

```
echo "<table width='900'>";

foreach($results as $row) {
    echo "<tr>";

    echo "<td>";
    echo htmlspecialchars($row['serial']) . "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo htmlspecialchars($row['model']) . "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo htmlspecialchars($row['deviceCondition']) . "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo htmlspecialchars($row['sealCondition']) . "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo htmlspecialchars($row['location']) . "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo htmlspecialchars($row['deployDate']) . "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo htmlspecialchars($row['weight']) . "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo htmlspecialchars($row['notes']) . "</td>";
    echo '</tr>';

    //Arrays
    $serials [] = htmlspecialchars($row['serial']); //serial as an array
    $models [] = htmlspecialchars($row['model']); //model as an array
    $deviceConditions [] = htmlspecialchars($row['deviceCondition']);//deviceCondition as an array
    $locations [] = htmlspecialchars($row['location']); //location as an array
    $deployDates [] = htmlspecialchars($row['deployDate']); //deployDate as an array
    $weights [] = htmlspecialchars($row['weight']); //weight as an array
    $notess [] = htmlspecialchars($row['notes']); //notes as an array
}

echo "</table>";
```

Comment: `<tr>` should still be inside the loop.

Comment: yeah that's my fault. my original comment didn't include the tr tags. I was thinking of something else